# AngularJS isolated scope variable in directive not being set

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I have a directive that looks like this:

```
return {
                restrict: 'A',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    personId: '@',
                    relationshipId: '@',
                    relationshipColumnsShown: '@',
                    personColumnsShown: '@'
                },
                templateUrl: 'app/views/communication/displayList.html',
                controller: controller,
                require: ['$scope', 'communicationLogDataService']
            };
```

You can see that there is a property called personId, which I am setting in the parent directive that is using the above directive like this

```
<div data-display-communication-log="" data-personId="currentPerson.Id" data-relationship-Columns-Shown="true" data-person-Columns-Shown="false">
</div>
```

You can see the personId is being set to the currentPerson.Id property from the parent directive.  Now in the child directive I have a watch setup on the personId value.  This watch is only getting hit once when the child directive is first loaded and the value is undefined.  When it is first loaded the currentPerson on the parent doesn't exist yet because it is loaded Async. in the parent (not sure if this is what is causing the problem).

So my question is how can I pass the Id of the currentPerson from the parent into the personId of the child?

Comment: kindly share a fiddle please

Comment: Have you tried '=' instead of '@' ?

Comment: I have tried both = and @.  @ is more correct for what I'm doing because I only want the information to travel from the parent to the child, but I have tried both

Comment: I fairly new to Angular and JS, so I have never really created a Fiddle before.  I'm having trouble getting the fiddle setup.  Here is the basics of what I'm trying to do, but even that is not working.  If you could help me understand what I'm missing from the Fiddle I can continue with the example.  http://jsfiddle.net/jgpNT/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the @ binding for the isolate scope, it only gives you the string value of the attribute, it does not evaluate it as an expression.  I made a couple changes to your Fiddle to make it work.  Needed an ng-app added, change the attribute name on your directive (camel case doesn't work in the template for attribute names) and put double curlies around your expression so it will get evaluated.  I also added an input element so you can see the data get updated, you don't need a watch in this situation.  Here is the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/pkqUn/3/

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">  
    <input ng-model="currentLog.RelationshipId"></input>
      <div>
          *<div data-personselect="" data-relationship-id="{{ currentLog.RelationshipId }}"></div>*
      </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('personselect', function() {
    return {
        template: '<span> test {{ relationshipId }}<span>',
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                relationshipId: '@'
            }
        };
});

function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.currentLog = {};
    $scope.currentLog.RelationshipId = 123;
}
```

Though this would prevent your directive from modifying the parent scope, I think it would be clearer to use the '=' isolate scope binding instead of '@', then you don't need the curlies around the attribute value.

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  I click on the link you provided and I don't see the changes you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to hit update on the fiddle.  I updated the link in the answer.  I'm used to using Plunker instead of JSFiddle.

Comment: thanks for the help.  I believe my only issue in my real code was the capitalization part.

Comment: Cool, that's kinda what I thought after fixing the fiddle.  Glad to help.